# Xamaron.forms IOS layout glitch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a layout glitch in the iOS version of my forms app.

I'm using NavigationPages so that the back button works properly in the Android version of the app.

I'm using `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false)` to hide the navigation bar on these pages, because my app needs all available screen real estate.

When I switch pages in iOS, the screen is initially laid out as if the navigation bar was present, then shifts up to take up the space where the navigation bar was, leaving a gap on the bottom of the screen.

So my app, which is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Ends up looking like this:

[image]

You can see the transition happen. [Here's a video of it](https://vid.me/EfsWs).

This only happens during navigation. If I then rotate the screen, that screen gets re-laid out and the gap is gone.

Comment: when/where do you call to hide the bar? constructor? may be you can try to call it after you create the page but before you call push? Also, what layout type you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can either call the `SetHasNavigationBar`  method in the Constructor of page you are navigating to (this should do the work):

```
public PageIamNavigatingTo()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

Or as @Yuri has indicated, you can call the method before pushing to a new page and once the page object has been created.

```
async void NavigateToMyOtherPage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var page = new MyOtherPage();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false);

    await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

In both cases the bar should be hidden before the page is rendered so you will not notice the animation when hiding.

Hope this helps.-